# Actual Date in an HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<tr>
    <td class="tr9 td0"><p class="p1 ft8">Mr. / Mrs. : </p></td>
    <td class="tr9 td1"><p class="p3 ft8"><nobr>Telefon: </nobr></p></td>
    <td class="tr9 td2"><p class="p4 ft6">DATE</p></td>                                     
</tr>
```

How can I become the actual Date in Javascript on the Placeholder "DATE" in this table?

```
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>")
```

Doesnt work.

Comment: Where did you try to put that JavaScript code, and how did it fail to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are writing value directly to HTML. Pass it to element

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
document.getElementsByClassName('p4')[0].innerHtml = "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>";
```

Or if you are using jQuery:

```
$('.p4').text("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>");
```

[JSFiddle with pure js and jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/tfB7b/)

Comment: @user3714925 `does not work` says nothing to me. Blue screen of death, computer blows up, browser hangs, console full of errors or something?

Comment: No error (in firebug), but it show no Date on this Place.

Comment: @user3714925 sorry, `innerHTML` with capitals HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript code is working fine but the problem with `document.write`. it write text on entire document.

so use.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('p4').innerHTML= "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>";
```

Comment: Will throw `innerHtml is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug in firebug and it's seems textcontent property still filled by "DATE", so i set the textContent property become date today, code below maybe can answer your question :

```
<script>
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    document.getElementsByClassName('p4')[0].textContent = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
</script>
```